# React, access value stored in a td through a react ref

Tags: reactjs

I have a `React` ref defined like so

```
<td ref="denominationValue" className="denomination-item">20</td>
```

I simply want to get the 20 stored inside the `<td>`.

`ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity)` returns `<td class="denomination-item">50</td>`

But when I do `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity).value.trim()`, I get undefined.

I've done a lot of searching, but everything I've found talks about either `<form>` or `<input>`

How do I get the `20` as a string, or even a number?

Comment: it should be `this.refs.denominationValue` because you name it as `denominationValue`.

Comment: Try `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity).textContent.trim()` since td don't have a value attribute

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri. It worked. Please make it into an answer so I can accept it. I simply wrapped the result in `Number` to make it into a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`td` doesn't have an attribute names `value` defined on it and hence `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity).value` doesn't work, you should instead get the inner content you `innerText` or `textContent` like

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity).textContent
```

In order to convert it into an integer you could make use of parseFloat

```
parseFloat(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.quantity).textContent)
```